# iOS - In app purchase for dynamic Prices & Products

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

My App  display dynamic products & prices. User adds them into cart & make payment.
Now some products are digital (used within App)after buying them user able to download pdf or watch video.
I was using Braintree payment gateway for payment. I submitted my app but apple rejected it mentioning implementation of IN App Purchase as it involves digital goods.
Now I have outlaid a solution but not sure wether it is feasible or not &  is it in accordance with apple review guidelines

As my app has dynamic product & prices

So let's suppose I have to pay an amount of $147
I have created 5 Consumable IAP of price $100, $40, $5, $2, $10 in itunes connect
Now At Payment I request for all  consumable IAP’s which I have configured  & I shows user single options of paying $147 and make request for payment of IAP valued ($100,$40,$5,$2) totalling $147 at once.
My constraint is that I want only a single option for user to purchase dynamic price & creating wallet balance is not applicable in my case.

**So please help me as I want make sure that my solution is in accordance with apple guidelines & also programmatically feasible before implementation. Any suggestion will be Great. Thank in advance!!**

Comment: can you tell what exactly Apple have replied. can you copy paste it here?

Comment: Apple has replied "we noticed that your app enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the in-app purchase API, which is not appropriate for the App Store.
Next Steps
While the payment system that you have included may conduct the transaction outside of the app, if the purchasable content, functionality, or services are intended to be used in the app, they must be purchased through in-app purchase, within the app - unless it is of the type referenced in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines."

Comment: 3.1.3 you should follow this guideline of Apple.

Comment: 3.1.3 is about “Reader” Apps which is not applicable in my case